# Cross-Referencing Label Affects Vertical Spacing

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, cleveref, vertical-spacing, tikz-pic

Consider the code with `\label{L}` (immediately above the second tikzpicture) commented out:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\textwidth=4in \textheight=6.40in \voffset -7pt \evensidemargin=-10pt

\usepackage{cleveref,lipsum}
\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{someblue}{RGB}{197,213,255}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=someblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[1]} \vskip -6pt \hfill \textbf{\emph{Lorem Ipsum}} 
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

%\label{L}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=someblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[2]} \vskip -6pt \hfill \textbf{\emph{Lorem Ipsum}} 
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

%\newpage
%\noindent Why does the label command add additional vertical space on \cpageref{L}?
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Now, if I run the code again---this time without `\label{L}` commented out---the vertical space between the two tikzpictures is increased:

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: Why does the `\label` command affect the vertical spacing between the two tikzpictures; and how, if possible, may I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: The title of your query is a bit misleading, as the presence of `\label{L}` affects the placement of the second tikzpicture regardless of whether or not `cleveref` is loaded. Please fix.

Comment: Instead of ending `center` and restarting, just use one environment and `\vskip \topskip` after `\label{L}`.

Comment: @cfr That seems to work; thank you. Should it be expected that `\label` would cause  extra vertical space?

Comment: @IdleCustard Pretty much expected, yes. The `\label` comes after the space added at the end of the first `center` and before the space added at the start of the next `center`. Because that is broken up by the `\label`, LaTeX inserts both spaces. If there were no label there, it would figure out that it should only insert one because you don't usually want double vertical space inserted. Basically, the detection doesn't distinguish between an invisible insertion and a visible one, where you'd want both spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\label` can affect spacing if used in vertical mode. The effect would be less of you had one center environment or would go completely if it was immediately after the first `\end{tikzpicture}`, so: `\end{tikzpicture}\label{L}`

The space increases as `center` adds vertical space before and after the centred block but, like most latex display constructs, it checks for any immediately preceding space and arranges the vertical space used is the maximum of the existing space and the space about to be added. The label generates a `\write` node which prevents the second `center` looking up and seeing the space added by the first one, so you get a double space, the space at the end of the first `center` then the `\label` node then the space at the start of the second `center`.

Apart from affecting space this is a bad label position for other reasons. As there is no referenceable counter, this is presumably for a `\pageref` but there are page break positions before and after the label so you could get a reference to either page. You should use `\end{tikzpicture}\label{L}` if you want to label the end of the first tikzpicture or use `\leavevmode\label{L}\begin{tikzpicture}` if you want to label the start of the second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and helpful comments.